# Beginner Java: go back to start after failed try (try contains for loop)

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch, do-while

I want this to start over if the try fails. I have found many answers to vaguely similar situations, but not with the for loop and with my structure. Doing this is not required and will not benefit my assignment, but I just want to do it. The program works as it is required to and beyond (yes this is very beginner stuff). I've tried and tried with do...while and for loops, and I either get infinite loops, can't find symbol, etc. I know if I keep trying I will get it, and I also have a hunch about some of my mistakes, but I really want someone experienced to look at this and make a suggestion.

```
try{                            

  System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
  int original = sc.nextInt();

  int entry = Math.abs(original);  

  String str = new Integer(entry).toString();

  int len = str.length();           

  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("The entry is " + len + " digits long.");
  System.out.println();
  System.out.print("The digits entered are: ");

  int runningTotal;  
  int ttl = 0;      

for (int i=1; i<=len; i++){
  System.out.print(str.charAt(i-1) + " "); 
  char num1 = str.charAt(i-1);             
  String num2 = Character.toString(num1);  
  runningTotal = Integer.parseInt(num2);  
  ttl = ttl + runningTotal;
}
System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("The sum of the digits entered is: " + ttl + "\n");
}
catch (InputMismatchException imeRef){
System.out.println("Data type error: " + imeRef.toString() +"\n"
                    + "No letters or special characters allowed.");
}
```

Comment: you can use `while` loop...until you success then `break`

Comment: Why would you want to try it over again? What would you expect to have changed to make it not throw an exception?

Comment: One would expect that after being told "No letters or special characters allowed" that the user would enter a valid input (int). Putting only the necessary statements inside the try block would definitely improve the situation though.

Comment: I know what I'm trying to do is silly. Basically, I want the user to enter an integer, and if they enter something that doesn't work, I want to tell the user, "you entered bad stuff, please try again," and have the program prompt them again. My wording of "no special characters" in my message is misleading, and easily changed. I do appreciate you all taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to put the *whole* thing in a `try..catch` block? Wrap only the bit that's error prone.

In any case, this code is in a function - if you really want to start over on error, try this:

```
void foo() {
   try {
      doSomeDangerousThing();
   catch(Exception e) {
      foo()
   }
}
```

Of course, this is a dangerous game to play - if it raised an error on the last call, why won't it on this call, if nothing changed? You potentially create a deadly infinite loop. Unless the parameters change, the error will most likely recur.

If you want to just run code over and over and over, use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

using while loop

try this

```
while(true){
        try{                            
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
            int original = sc.nextInt();
            int entry = Math.abs(original);  

            String str = new Integer(entry).toString();

            int len = str.length();           

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The entry is " + len + " digits long.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("The digits entered are: ");

            int runningTotal;  
            int ttl = 0;      

            for (int i=1; i<=len; i++){
                  System.out.print(str.charAt(i-1) + " "); 
                  char num1 = str.charAt(i-1);             
                  String num2 = Character.toString(num1); 
                  runningTotal = Integer.parseInt(num2);  
                  ttl = ttl + runningTotal;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("The sum of the digits entered is: " + ttl + "\n");
            break;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException imeRef){
            System.out.println("Data type error: " + imeRef.toString() +"\n"
                            + "No letters or special characters allowed.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but that one causes an infinite loop if invalid data type are entered.

Comment: because you only handle `InputMismatchException`

Answer (score 0):

Try making a method:

```
public int askForInt() {
    int input;
    try {
        input = sc.nextInt();
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException imeRef) {
        System.out.println(" Try again, etc...");
        askForInt();
    }
    return input;
}
```

and then after you ask the user for the integer the first time just call the method:

```
System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
int original = askForInt();
// proceed
```